# Running services

Tags: services

Is there a way to get **precise** list of services with "is running"/"is not running" statuses specified.

```
service --status-all
```

outputs more than 30 `?` services.

Why is that output is so not informative? Is it that difficult to determine if service is running or not? And how to get the exact statuses for all services?

```
zerkms@ubuntu-server-11:~$ sudo service --status-all 2>&1|grep cron
 [ ? ]  cron
zerkms@ubuntu-server-11:~$ sudo service cron status
cron start/running, process 804
```

Comment: @Rinzwind: it returns several services with `+` and `-`, but most of services are marked with `?`. It is just installed ubuntu-server 11.04

Comment: @Rinzwind: added the output sample to clarify what I mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems a bug in the `service` script. Changing the grep pattern in line 77 with this gives better results:

```
"\(^\|\W\)status)"
```

**Edit**

Found a bug report in Debian on this. A patch is available, functionally equivalent to what I write above: [service doesn't correctly parse "cron" init.d](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=619582). Launchpad do not recognize the project `sysvinit-utils`.

Comment: Yep, now looks much better. Could you please file a bug then? (I'm not proficient in ubuntu at all, and don't even know where their bug tracker is) ;-)

Comment: Of course, i'll do, if it is not signaled yet

Comment: ok. Checked your answer. PS: please add a reference to a bug then after, so I could track it ;-)

Comment: thanks for the reference. Surprisingly the bug committer chose the `cron` too ;-)

Comment: Thanks, that fixed most of the ?s, though not all.  Among others Citadel is still showing a ?.