# How do you get a list of all starting services?

Tags: 10.04, startup, services

I know about the `update-rc.d SERVICE OPTIONS` command to add and remove services from startup, but how do I use it to get a list of all the services that are currently configured to start at startup?

Is there some other way to get this list?

Answer (score 241, accepted):

See the attached link.

[UbuntuBootupHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto)

The command is

```
service --status-all
```

Comment: Thanks, the `service --status-all` did it, though I still have to find a legend to determine exactly what those symbols mean.

Comment: @Lance: there is a bug in managing option `--status-all`, see this AU question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55992/running-services

Comment: I realize this is a little dated, but from my reading of the man page, it sounds as if this lists the current status, not whether they're configured to start?  "service --status-all runs all init scripts, in alphabetical order, with the status command. This option only calls status for sysvinit jobs, upstart jobs can be queried in a similar manner with initctl list'."

Comment: List of pretty much everything relevant that is running

`initctl list | egrep -v " stop/waiting|^tty" ; service --status-all 2>&1 | egrep -v "\[ (\?|\-) \]"`

Comment: `+` =  running, `-` = stopped service. `?` = managed by upstart (run `initctl list` to get the status of these)

Comment: Does anyone know how to pipe this to less or a file? Using `service --status-all > myfile.txt 2&>1` writes a few lines to the file, and leaves the rest as output on the terminal. I can't grep the output either.

Comment: This lists the services that *have been started*, not the services that *will be started upon booting the server* which is what the original question asks for.

Comment: Does this require `systemd`?

Answer (score 8):

You could use [BUM](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/bum).

[image]

Comment: This looks nice, but I'm too new with Ubuntu to know how to install this on my virtual server, that I PuTTY into (or if it's even possible).

Comment: Do you have a graphical environment?

Comment: No, just a terminal session.

Comment: Well, BUM is a graphical tool, so the command you've mentioned above seems to fit better yours needs.

Comment: You can install this without graphical tools. X apps can run remotely. Yes, even on Windows. You just have to tell each app where to run (e.g. IP address). It's possible, you can Google the specifics.