# How to start and stop a service?

Tags: services, upstart, init.d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the recommended way to enable / disable services?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/whats-the-recommended-way-to-enable-disable-services)

Are there any other command to start stop restart service in ubuntu other than the below following.

1. `service --status-all`
2. `service <service name> stop`
3. `sudosysv-rc-conf`

Comment: which service do you wish to start/stop/restart? there is at least a way to do it in several services but I think you should be more specific on your needs. I don't think there is a way to start/stop/restart all the services at the same time.

Comment: for example if i wanted to stop nginx,I would do something like this $service nginx stop; I wanted to know if there are any other alternative ways to stop and start a service. Any GUI based application that displays or shows us the unused services etc.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a GUI client called BUM. If you're interested in GUIs, you should edit your answer to take out "command." Generally when people are looking for a "command" they aren't interested in a GUI.

Comment: You may find interesting the answers in this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/whats-the-recommend-way-to-enable-disable-services.

Comment: The duplicate is wrong: this is not about enabling/disabling, but starting/stopping. Also, this question has an accepted answer.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Answers [there](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/recommended-way-to-enable-disable-services), including [its accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/19324/22949), also include information about how to start and stop services. Furthermore, the topics are naturally very closely related--anyone who wants to enable and disable services will probably want to know how to start and stop them as well, and *most* people who want to know how to start and stop them will likely also want to know how to enable and disable them. So I'm not sure.

Comment: @EliahKagan: oops, you are right. :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It depends largely on the service. The new and preferred way to stop start and restart services is through `/etc/init.d`. So, for example, to stop or start the Apache Webserver, you can run

`/etc/init.d/apache2 stop`

`/etc/init.d/apache2 start`

The same is true of many other services, but probably not all. You can use the utility `sysv-rc-conf` to see which services you have that use an `init.d` script and manage them that way as well. Run it with `sudo sysv-rc-conf`.

If you're looking for a GUI application, try Boot up Manager. Install with

`apt-get install bum`

and run from the UI or from a terminal with

`sudo bum`

[Usage and documentation can be found here.](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/bumdocs.html)

Comment: Boot-up Manager (bum) is very nice to have an easy report of services on our system.

Comment: Why is the preferred method to use the binary in init.d/ and not the service manager `service` as part of the [sysvinit-utils](https://packages.debian.org/sid/sysvinit-utils) package?

Comment: @ThorSummoner it used to be but these days I think upstart is the prefered way.

Comment: Update: from Ubuntu 15.104 "Vivid" Canonical dropped `upstart` and switched to another init system, called `systemd`, adopted also by Debian and other major distros such as Arch, Fedora, RedHat and SuSe. So, unlike to `upstart`, seems reasonable to consider that `systemd` it's here to stay, for quite a long time.

Answer (score 58):

You can use the following commands:

```
service <servicename> stop

service <servicename> start

service <servicename> restart
```

Note `service --status-all` doesn't stop or start anything, it just returns a status (and there's some [known bugs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55992/running-services) in it).

If you have `upstart` then you can use these:

```
stop <servicename>

start <servicename>

restart <servicename>
```

Comment: The latter (using upstart) is the preferred way in Ubuntu now.

Comment: Note that upstart is installed by default on Ubuntu [since 6.10](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: `upstart` has now been [deprecated by Ubuntu since v15](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseNotes)