# High fan speed after suspend

Tags: 14.04, suspend, fan, sony

It seems this is a common problem, but I still cannot find a good solution. After a cold boot, my laptop runs perfectly, but after resuming from suspend, the fan kicks in to 100% and blows out cold air, indicating that the fan isn't responding to the temperature of the laptop components. As proof, here's the output from sensors:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +41.0°C  (crit = +101.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +43.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +43.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +39.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

My laptop model is Sony SVE14A290X. I have tried adding a couple different 99fancontrol.d scripts, but none worked so far. pwmconfig also doesn't report a pwm-capable module in my laptop. Please help!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately `fancontrol` doesn't restore the fan state after suspension. You can write a [`pm-action(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pm-hibernate.8.html) resume hook that restarts the `fancontrol` service:

1. Create a file `/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_fancontrol` (e. g. with `gksudo gedit`):

   ```sh
   #!/bin/sh
   case "$1" in
   resume)
       exec service fancontrol restart;;
   esac
   ```
2. Mark it executable:

   ```sh
   sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_fancontrol
   ```

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58404/how-to-start-and-stop-a-service

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!

Comment: fancontrol is not even installed by default (at least in Xubuntu 15.10).

Answer (score 0):

On more recent Ubuntu using systemd, you need a similar script but in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
post)
  exec service fancontrol restart;;
esac
```

Comment: I don't think it worked.

Comment: Worked for me. May need to mark it executable

Comment: This was from another question, but it seems like there was some sort of bug that got fixed in kernel 4.12.  If you follow this guide to manually installed the latest kernel (via .debs) this will fix the problem.

https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-kernel-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

I followed the suggestion for systemd and it worked briefly.  It appears to me that it may work only on the first suspend/resume cycle after a cold boot.

I tried restarting the fancontrol service manually but it was 'masked' and permission denied.  I tried unmasking it but that did not solve the problem.

Folks have speculated that this issue is a kernel regression.  Upon searching it is seen cropping up over the past ten years.  Laptops mentioned include Dell, HP, and Lenovo.

I am having the issue on a new Lenovo X1-Carbon, 5th generation, running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS Gnome, all updates current, kernel 4.10.0-28-generic.